RabitTracker in Xgboost listening on random port. How to assign a fixed port to the tracker?
How do we assign fixed listening port to XGBoost rabittracker ? It seems to listen on some random port.
Below is the sample code:
from xgboost.tracker import RabitTracker
tracker = RabitTracker(n_workers=2, host_ip='127.0.0.1', port=1234, sortby="task")
tracker.start()
print(tracker.worker_args())

It prints out random ports. Eg. {'dmlc_tracker_port': 34195, 'dmlc_tracker_uri': '127.0.0.1'}
